# How to add a decimal point in floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is an example:

```
var = float(input("Type in something: "))
var2 = round(var, 2)
print(var2)
```

How do I make it so if the user inputs a decimal with just the tenths place(example: 4.6), it will add a 0 at the end?

Comment: `"{:.2f}".format(var)`

Comment: ...or equivalently `f"{var2:.2f}"`